# Android: Debugging over RDP

Tags: android, debugging, remote-desktop, rdp

I am trying to figure out how to debug with Android Studio from a virtual machine which I am connected with over RDP.

I've got a physical machine(Win 7) and a virtual machine(Win 8.1) which runs on a sever. I am connected from the local machine to the virtual machine over RDP.

I only found solutions which include the use of a WiFi-Network. Solutions with WiFi are not possible for me.

Does anyone have experience with this? Is it possible?

Comment: What's the problem?  Why can't you fire up Android Studio and debug as normal?

Comment: The problem is that no device can be found. This is not surprising because the Android-Device is plugged in to the Physical Machine and the IDE is running on the Virtual Machine which I am connected to.

Comment: I use this http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-for-remote-desktop.html

Comment: @LKYeung It's too much expensive for a simple task.